# Calculate distance between SVG elements (including text)

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, collision-detection

I am looking for JavaScript approaches to calculate the horizontal and vertical distances between two SVG elements with arbitrary content (paths, shapes, use references, text and combinations thereof). Bounding box distance is not enough, I need the closest horizontal and vertical distances e.g. of something like these two interlocking L shapes:

```html
<svg>
<text y="20">L</text>
<text y="15" x="7">L</text>
<svg>
```

So far I did not find anything that would help me with that. The problem is somehow similar to collision detection, but not quite. There are many collision detection tutorials using bounding boxes or specific shapes, but nothing that works with the precise shapes of arbitrary elements.

If I had to roll my own, I'd probably render each element to a different canvas and then count how many pixels lie between them (or render them to the same canvas with different colors).

Comment: I think the roll your own canvas solution is the only viable option.

Comment: If you want a brute force N^2 approach: for each point on a shape, calculate the distance to every point on the other shape. The minimum distance is what you want.